# How to convert time to hours only (php)?

Tags: php, algorithm, function, time

I need little function in `PHP` which will convert hour:minutes only to hours.

a.g.

```
15:30 = 15.5
15:15 = 15.25
15:45 = 15.75
```

and so on

Thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    function timeToDecimal($time) {
        $hm = explode(":", $time);
        return ($hm[0] + ($hm[1]/60));
    }


    $time = "15:15";
    echo timeToDecimal($time);

?>
```

Output:

```
15.25
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
function toDecimalTime($time)
{
    $parsed = date_parse($time);
    return $parsed["hour"] + $parsed["minute"] / 60;
}
```

Comment: The way Rizier123 solves the problem is performanter than your way. http://3v4l.org/gMrhW

Comment: It really depends on usage whether it's important for this code to be highly efficient. In most cases, it wouldn't be!