# PHP: display 90 min as 1.5 hours

Tags: php, time, time-format

Minutes=90
Need to display in hours

```
echo intdiv($ct['time'], 60).'.'. ($ct['time'] % 60)." Hours";
```

The output is 1:30 hours.

But i need to display as 1.5 hours.
How to convert  the minute into hours? As 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2 hours and so on .

Comment: 30 / 60 is .5, isn't it?

Comment: I think `1:20` is going to be more useful to people than `1.3333333333`.

Comment: If I can add a note about terminology, `1:30` is the human readable form. `1.9` looks more like a machine representation (unless such format happens to be used in some culture I'm not aware of).

Comment: _IMHO_ 1.50 is less "human readable". I would assume it's 1 hour 50 mins. Like what time is `1.957`?

Comment: Is there a way to display as required

Comment: 90 / 60 = 1.5…‽

Comment: It's hard to find dupes for super-basic questions sometimes.  This is as close as I can get at the moment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27474671/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/53554315/2943403

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is the given code even related to Laravel or CodeIgniter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Time String to Decimal Hours PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595935/convert-time-string-to-decimal-hours-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with all the comments saying that it will be clearer to display `1h20` than `1.33 hours`. You may could round it and display `1 h and ½` or `1 hour and ¼` but still, it's not easy to read.

If you want to stick to your hours then you could do this:

```php
$min = $cat['prepration_time'];
if ($min < 60) {
    echo $min == 1 ? "$min minute" : "$min minutes";
}
else {
    $hours = round($min / 60, 1);
    echo $hours == 1 ? "$hours hour" : "$hours hours";
}
```

Examples of output:

```
1 minute
20 minutes
50 minutes
1 hour
1.2 hours
1.5 hours
1.7 hours
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have one variable that stores an amount of minutes, `$cat['prepration_time']` in your case. To output the minutes as decimal hours all you really need to do is to divide the number of minutes by 60, that's the number of minutes in one hour. In your case that would be

```php
echo $cat['preparation_time'] / 60 . ' hours';
```

To avoid awkward results like `1.33333333333 hours`, you can additionally wrap the calculation in [round](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.round.php), where the second parameter of `round` is the precision, i.e. the number of digits behind the dot.

```php
$minutes = 77;
echo round($minutes / 60, 2) . ' hours'; // 1.28 hours
```

Be aware however that this format is badly readable and prone to misunderstanding. Does `1.30 hours` mean `1 hour and 30 minutes` or rather `1 hour and 18 minutes`? And while you might be able to convert `1.30 hours` in your head, you will surely need a calculator for `1.283 hours`. I would recommend to use a commonly understood and unambiguous format, like for example `1 hour and 32 minutes`, or `1:32 hours`.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code.

Firstly add the hour and minutes after that I have added round function so it will show proper output upto 2 decimal.

$hours =1; $minutes=30 ; $CalculateHours = $hours + round($minutes / 60, 2); echo $CalculateHours  . " hours";

Result: 1.5 Hours

Comment: Why? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I have already mention the brief code with proper steps.

Comment: So, how would your code work with the given sample input of `$minutes = 90` from the question?

Comment: @NicoHaase for that $hours =0; $minutes= 90 ; $CalculateHours = $hours + round($minutes / 60, 2);  echo $CalculateHours;